# How to generate a thumbnail of an openlayers map?

Tags: openlayers-2

I would like to allow the user to generate a thumbnail image of what the user is seeing in the OpenLayers map canvas so the user may print, save, share, email, or whatever.

**Any ideas of how i would go about doing this?**

I'm looking for solutions that generate an image. I don't want to save the innerHTML, feature data or anything other than an image. An image is much easier to share and cannot later be modified.

Examples:

[image]

or this will also work:

[image]

Comment: Judging by this link http://trac.osgeo.org/openlayers/wiki/Printing all your options are fraught and a bit hacky, depending on what access you have to the server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've been looking at some of the new functionality in the development version of the OpenLayers library, and there is a [demo](http://dev.openlayers.org/sandbox/camptocamp/canvas/openlayers/examples/exportMapCanvas.html) of this exact feature. In  this example, it enables an image to be generated using the basemap, a wms and a vector overlay. The example seems to work on Firefox ok (but every so often I get a string of errors while the page load), Safari seems fine as does Chrome. I'm having a hard time getting it to work on my own server for my own application as it does require lots of reworking of code. Many pieces are not compatible with the current openlayers library.

[image]

Comment: I'd love to see other examples! I'm unfamiliar with the Openlayers development process, so I'm not sure if it's necessary for me to change all of my code so it works with this development version, or whether to wait....

Comment: I'll try to put together a test example that would work with my app ( with WFS and WMS layers) and i'll post back here.

Answer (score 2):

Could you use the [GeoExt](http://geoext.org/index.html) javascript library? They have a demo of printing to a pdf [here](http://api.geoext.org/1.0/examples/print-extent.html):

[image]

It does require the Mapfish or Geoserver printing module.

Comment: This generates a PDF, i need an image. Close though.

Comment: I think the MapFish printing also supports PNG output. It is the PDF that is the tricky part. http://www.mapfish.org/doc/print/protocol.html

Comment: Are you using PostGIS to store the data? There is a PostGIS output to `geoJson`, and then using advice from @geographika's blog you can convert geoJson to png. http://geographika.co.uk/visualising-geojson-in-15-minutes

Comment: Final thought - it seems like this might be most easily done using the webserver, rather than in browser. Geoserver (for example) can output to png http://opengeo.org/technology/geoserver/ as could Mapserver, Mapnik ....

Answer (score 1):

If you are willing to accept a Google-Chrome-only solution I have created a Chrome plugin that takes a screenshot of the current tab, crops out the ol div and renders it on a canvas.

From there thumbnailing, printing, sharing, whatever is just a matter of spicing up to taste the HTML.

It's on github:

https://github.com/unicolet/chrome_print_ext

p.s.: parts of the text are in Italian, but I'll translate it if needed.

p.s.2: it might require some slight modifications to work in your app, but I'll be glad to help.

Comment: what a shame, sorry, i need it to work on all modern browsers.