# Print library for OpenLayers?

Tags: openlayers-2, printing

I realize this is a bit of an open question but are there any known open JavaScript libraries which facilitate printing an OpenLayers map?  I'm looking to produce the content on the client and possibly upload it to convert to PDF or simply set the innerHTML on some DOM element.

I started a [proof-of-concept](http://pastebin.com/Zi9XKpw0) but was looking for something which honors various tile sizes and vector markup (IE 8) and all the other complexities that are sure to arise.

Comment: What is the source of your map? If it is eg mapserver or mapguide, you could consider rendering your image there.

Comment: Unknown at design time and varied (Public - Google, Bing, OSM, ArcGIS as well as ArcGIS/ArcIMS, MapGuide, WMS, ...).  I'd like a client-side solution for collecting the imagery and vector markup.  Once collected probably upload to convert to PDF.  Need to embed map in a document.

Answer (score 5):

I've asked a [similar question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/17941/how-to-generate-a-thumbnail-of-an-openlayers-map) .

Best answer was using `OpenLayers.Control.ExportMap()` to generate an image of the canvas.

Here's a [DEMO](http://dev.openlayers.org/sandbox/camptocamp/canvas/openlayers/examples/exportMapCanvas.html).

Comment: We rolled our own few years back because there wasn't anything available. And it's significant amount of dev. And also had to support older browsers w/o Canvas.  If starting anew and supporting only modern browsers this looks like the way to go.

Comment: I'd be curious to know the challenges you faced.  I need to run in IE 8.

Comment: CaptDragon - had to change my question...looking for IE 8 solution otherwise ExportMap + Canvas.toDataURL() was everything I was looking for.

Comment: Looks like `toDataURL` has *better* support in OL3, and there has also been suggested an alternate `toBlob` approach: https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/issues/2968

Answer (score 1):

I've posted this answer on SO for a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18519251/openlayers-print-function/).

This export function will allow you to generate a dataURL for your map, which you can use to produce a PDF (I'm using jsPDF).

This solution is dependent on [html2canvas.js](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/)

```
    function exportMap() {

        var mapElem = document.getElementById('map'); // the id of your map div here

        // html2canvas not able to render css transformations (the container holding the image tiles uses a transform)
        // so we determine the values of the transform, and then apply them to TOP and LEFT 
        var transform=$(".gm-style>div:first>div").css("transform");
        var comp=transform.split(","); //split up the transform matrix
        var mapleft=parseFloat(comp[4]); //get left value
        var maptop=parseFloat(comp[5]);  //get top value
        $(".gm-style>div:first>div").css({ //get the map container. not sure if stable
          "transform":"none",
          "left":mapleft,
          "top":maptop,
        });

        html2canvas(mapElem, {
          useCORS: true,
          onrendered: function(canvas) {
             mapImg = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');

            // reset the map to original styling
            $(".gm-style>div:first>div").css({
              left:0,
              top:0,
              "transform":transform
            });

            // do something here with your mapImg
            // e.g. I then use the dataURL in a pdf using jsPDF...
            // createPDFObject();
          }
        });
    }
```

**Note**

- Only tested on Chrome and Firefox
- This is a hacky solution (unfortunately I am struggling to find other options for my situation)
- If you have the option to use Openlayers 3, there seems to be better canvas support, and I've also seen a convincing toBlob example: http://codepen.io/barbalex/pen/raagKq